Modify the ffmpeg command to work with more than one image
ffmpeg -y -i image.jpg -filter_complex "[0:v] scale=1280:-1,loop=-1:size=2,trim=0:40,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,setsar=1,crop='w=1280:h=720:x=0:y=min(max(0, t - 3), (40 - 3 - 3)) / (40 - 3 - 3) * (ih-oh)'" unix.mp4
I want to edit the above command so it can be used for multiple images or a folder containing many images. And give all images used the same size and aspect ratio. Please help me, thank you everyone.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The above command is being used for an image, specifically I have a set of 15 images and I want them to run from bottom to top and output in a single video.

I don't know what's your OS, so I publish general answer how to loop ffmpeg-command - well, you can  modify to any command over files - in command line - the website contains multiple code examples.
https://ottverse.com/convert-all-files-inside-folder-ffmpeg-batch-convert/
